# Orbit Camera with Track Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, математика

Есть такой скрипт. Пытаюсь к нему приделать траекторию. Допустим у меня есть здание буквой L. Мне нужно чтобы камера крутилась не по кругу как сейчас, а по траектории которая бы зависела от расстояния камеры до стен здания.
Например, расстояние до стены или потолка должно быть не меньше 50f.

Кто-то поможет?)

```
 using System;
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/OrbitCam")]
[RequireComponent(typeof(RoomOrbitCamMouse))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(RoomOrbitCamKeys))]
public class RoomOrbitCam : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform Target;

public float Distance;          // Desired distance (units, ie Meters)
public float Rotation;          // Desired rotation (degrees)
public float Tilt;              // Desired tilt (degrees)

public bool Smoothing;          
public float ZoomDampening;     
public float RotationDampening; 
public float TiltDampening;     

public float MinDistance;       // Minimum distance of camera from target
public float MaxDistance;       // Maximum distance of camera from target

public float MinRotation;       // Minimum rotation (degrees)
public float MaxRotation;       // Maximum rotation (degrees)

public float MinTilt;           // Minimum tilt (degrees)
public float MaxTilt;           // Maximum tilt (degrees)

public bool CollisionDetection;              
public float CameraRadius = 0.5f;
public bool AutoSetIgnoreLayers = false;
public LayerMask CollisionIgnoreLayerMask;   

public bool FollowBehind;                           
public float FollowRotationOffset;                  

//
// PRIVATE VARIABLES
//

private float _currDistance;    // actual distance
private float _currRotation;    // actual rotation
private float _currTilt;        // actual tilt

//
// Unity METHODS
//

#region UNITY_METHODS

public void Reset()
{
    Smoothing = true;

    CollisionDetection = true;
    CameraRadius = 0.5f;
    CollisionIgnoreLayerMask = 0;    // "Nothing" by default!
    AutoSetIgnoreLayers = false;

    Distance = 16f;
    MinDistance = 2f;
    MaxDistance = 32f;

    Rotation = 0f;
    MinRotation = -180f;
    MaxRotation = 180f;

    Tilt = 45f;
    MinTilt = -15f;
    MaxTilt = 85f;

    TiltDampening = 5f;
    ZoomDampening = 5f;
    RotationDampening = 5f;

    FollowBehind = false;
    FollowRotationOffset = 0;
}

protected void Start()
{
    if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
    {
        // don't allow camera to rotate
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
    }

    //
    // set our current values to the desired values so that we don't "slide in"
    //
    _currDistance = Distance;
    _currRotation = Rotation;
    _currTilt = Tilt;
}

protected void Update()
{
}

protected void LateUpdate()
{
    if (Target == null)
        return;

    //
    // wrap and clamp values
    //

    Rotation = WrapAngle(Rotation);
    Tilt = WrapAngle(Tilt);

    Tilt = Mathf.Clamp(Tilt, MinTilt, MaxTilt);
    Distance = Mathf.Clamp(Distance, MinDistance, MaxDistance);
    Rotation = Mathf.Clamp(Rotation, MinRotation, MaxRotation);

    //
    // move from "desired" to "target" values
    //

    if (Smoothing)
    {
        _currRotation = Mathf.LerpAngle(_currRotation, Rotation, Time.deltaTime * RotationDampening);
        _currDistance = Mathf.Lerp(_currDistance, Distance, Time.deltaTime * ZoomDampening);
        _currTilt = Mathf.LerpAngle(_currTilt, Tilt, Time.deltaTime * TiltDampening);
    }
    else
    {
        _currRotation = Rotation;
        _currDistance = Distance;
        _currTilt = Tilt;
    }

    //
    // if we're following AND forcing behind, override the rotation to point to target (with offset)
    //

    if (FollowBehind)
    {
        ForceFollowBehind();
    }

    //
    // optionally, we'll check to make sure the target is visible
    //

    if (CollisionDetection)
    {
        if (AutoSetIgnoreLayers && CollisionIgnoreLayerMask == 0)
        {
            CollisionIgnoreLayerMask = 1 << Target.gameObject.layer;
        }

        CheckCollisions();
    }

    //
    // recalculate the actual position of the camera based on the above
    //

    UpdateCamera();
}

#endregion

//
// PUBLIC METHODS
//

#region PUBLIC_METHODS

/// <summary>
/// Snaps the current and desired camera position to the specified values
/// </summary>
/// <param name="distance"></param>
/// <param name="rotation"></param>
/// <param name="tilt"></param>
public void SnapTo(float distance, float rotation, float tilt)
{
    Distance = _currDistance = distance;
    Rotation = _currRotation = rotation;
    Tilt = _currTilt = tilt;
}

#endregion

//
// PRIVATE METHODS
//

#region PRIVATE_METHODS

/// <summary>
/// Update the camera position and rotation based on calculated values
/// </summary>
private void UpdateCamera()
{
    if (Target == null)
        return;

    var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(_currTilt, _currRotation, 0);
    var v = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -_currDistance);
    var position = rotation * v + Target.transform.position;

    if (GetComponent<Camera>().orthographic)
    {
        GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize = _currDistance;
    }

    // update position and rotation of camera
    transform.rotation = rotation;
    transform.position = position;
}

private RaycastHit[] _prevHits;
private void CheckCollisions()
{
    var direction = (transform.position - Target.transform.position);
    direction.Normalize();

    var distance = Distance;

    RaycastHit hitInfo;

    if (Physics.SphereCast(Target.transform.position, CameraRadius, direction, out hitInfo, distance, ~CollisionIgnoreLayerMask))
    {
        if (hitInfo.transform != Target)   // don't collide with ourself! ... hopefully, our target's layer is in the CollisionIgnoreLayerMask
        {
            _currDistance = hitInfo.distance - 0.05f;
        }
    }
}

private void ForceFollowBehind()
{
    var v = Target.transform.forward * -1;
    var angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, v);
    var sign = (Vector3.Dot(v, Vector3.right) > 0.0f) ? 1.0f : -1.0f;
    _currRotation = Rotation = 180f + (sign * angle) + FollowRotationOffset;
}

private float WrapAngle(float angle)
{
    while (angle < -180)
    {
        angle += 360;
    }
    while (angle > 180)
    {
        angle -= 360;
    }
    return angle;
}

#endregion
```

}

Comment: В стандарт ассетах есть скрипт с название что типо "protect wall", он избегает столкновения со стеной. Его можно взять за основу, также можно оттуда взять иерархию для построения камеры, она состоит из 3 объектов, root которая точь точь или через небольшой lerp следует за Target, pivot - который отвечает за наклоны и высоту, и сама камера отвечает за дальность от Target. Очень удобная схема. Используя только эти вещи, можно вашу идею сделать. Крутите просто root, а protectWall будет сама отдалять камеру от преград.
p.s. Функция WrapAngle доставила конечно...)

Comment: Спасибо) Буду пробовать)